# WordPress Custom Post Types

Tags: wordpress

I am currently trying to use WOrdPress custom post types to create a support ticket system currently i have what is below and it is working fine.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_support_tickets' );


function create_support_tickets() {
register_post_type( 'support_ticket',
array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => 'Tickets',
'singular_name' => 'Ticket',
'add_new' => 'Add New',
'add_new_item' => 'Add New Ticket',
'edit' => 'Edit',
'edit_item' => 'Edit Ticket',
'new_item' => 'New Ticket',
'view' => 'View',
'view_item' => 'View Ticket',
'search_items' => 'Search Tickets',
'not_found' => 'No Tickets found',
'not_found_in_trash' =>
'No Tickets found in Trash',
'parent' => 'Parent Ticket'
),
'public' => true,
'menu_position' => 15,
'supports' =>
array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments',
'thumbnail',  ),
'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
'menu_icon' =>
plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
'has_archive' => true
)
);
```

The code above works but i am not sure how to add categories for the tickets above and i want to be able to assign these tickets to other staff members who are WordPress Users with the role of staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial about **WordPress Custom Post Type**, each and every points are fully described that helps you a lot in future.

[WordPress Custom Post Type](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/08/complete-guide-custom-post-types/)

another example is here http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-your-first-wordpress-custom-post-type but I personally suggest you to follow the first one.

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in the function.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_services' );

function create_services() {
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('SERVICES', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('SERVICES', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'SERVICES'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New SERVICES'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit SERVICES'),
    'new_item' => __('New SERVICES'),
    'view_item' => __('View SERVICES'),
    'search_items' => __('Search SERVICES'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No SERVICES found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No SERVICES found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );

  $supports = array('title','editor','excerpt', 'trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes');

  register_post_type( 'services', 
    array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'supports' => $supports,
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'services', 'with_front' => false),
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: please edit and improve the code formatting. Also, you might consider adding a bit of explanation to the code :-)

Answer (score 0):

pass `'taxonomies' => array('category'),`. if you are using custom post types, you really need to understand taxonomies to make real use of custom post types in wp

Answer (score 0):

I have a tutorial on Custom Post Types - complete with HTML and CSS. http://fearlessflyer.com/create-a-testimonials-section-for-your-wordpress-site-the-right-way/

Answer (score -1):

```
      /**  Meet the team custom post 
You can use below wordpress script to create custom post type without any plugins */

      $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Team', 'Team', 'Team') ,
        'singular_name' => _x('Team', 'Team', 'rjis') ,
        'menu_name' => _x('Meet the Team', 'admin menu', 'rjis') ,
        'name_admin_bar' => _x('Team', 'add new on admin bar', 'rjis') ,
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Team', 'rjis') ,
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Team', 'rjis') ,
        'new_item' => __('New Team', 'rjis') ,
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Team', 'rjis') ,
        'view_item' => __('View Team', 'rjis') ,
        'all_items' => __('All Team Members', 'rjis') ,
        'search_items' => __('Search Team', 'rjis') ,
        'parent_item_colon' => __('Parent Team:', 'rjis') ,
        'not_found' => __('No Team found.', 'rjis') ,
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Team found in Trash.', 'rjis')
      );
      $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __('Description.', 'Meet the team') ,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
          'slug' => 'team'
        ) ,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array(
          'title',
          'editor',
          'author',
          'thumbnail',
          'excerpt'
        ) ,
        'menu_icon' => PLUGIN_URL . "images/team.png"
      );

     register_post_type('team', $args);
```